# x-model not binding to [value] attribute on select

Tags: alpine.js

So, I have a typical select with the x-model attribute like so:

```
<select class="py-1 border-gray-400 block w-full" x-model="tripData.clientOrder.operationType">
              <option value="transfer">Cruce</option>
              <option value="linehaul">Viaje</option>
              <option value="drayage">Movimiento Local</option>
</select>
```

The thing is the alpine property is being bound to what is inside the  tag, not what's specified on the [value] attribute.

If I change the selection, it correctly binds to the [value] attribute, but in some cases (most of them) the default selection is what's required.

Am I doing something wrong?

TIA!

Comment: Can you add the `x-data` portion of the code above? Will help in diagnosing the issue.

Comment: Hey @SteveO, thanks for the reply. I totally missed the notification of comment here. I solved the issue, and it was because I was setting it up wrong in the data. (As you were aiming I guess). Thanks anyways!